# Craft Admin CSS Broken..?

Tags: admin, css

I have had Craft CMS installed for a while. then today, I created some new pages, and pushed them with git to the templates folder, added them in sections etc, then, when I go to edit the entry, it comes out like this..?
[image]

That is my main sites styling/CSS, but craft shouldn't be using it...should it?

Every other admin page shows okay, and the frontend is fine... just when I edit the entries.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't push something to `craft/app/templates` if you did go check out the folder and remove anything that shouldn't belong there. You can check side by side which files shouldnt be in there with a fresh craft environment. Or just replace the `app` folder with a fresh one.